# Why converting a string to an integer is causing a runtime error?

Tags: python, arrays

The Question was this...

You are provided an array A of size N that contains non-negative integers. Your task is to determine whether the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers is divisible by 10.

And my solution was...

```
N = int(input())
A = input().split()
a = [i[-1] for i in A]
c = "".join(a)
d = int(c)
if d%10==0:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

When I tried to submit this code , a runtime error has occurred. The sample inputs were...
5
85 25 65 21 84
And the sample output was "No".
The code is giving a correct output but with a runtime error.

And this was the error log..

```
Exception Name: ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion
Exception Message: value has 82051 digits; use sys.set_int_max_str_digits() to increase the limit
Exception Line number: 5
```

```
a = [i[-1] for i in A]
c = "".join(a)
d = int(c)
if d%10==0:
    print("Yes")
```

What's the solution of this problem?

Comment: Isn't the solution simply that the last digit of the last number is zero?

Comment: The error is flagged in line 5: `d = int(c)` You need to check the value of `c` and then work out where your mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating something which is quite simple.

Since, you're joining the last digits of all the input numbers, and calculating modulus 10, you can simply check if the last digit of the last number is 0, which would make it a multiple of 10. It reduces the calculation time to a constant and you wouldn't need to typecast it to integer either this way.

```
n = int(input())
values = input().strip()

if values[-1] == '0':
    print("Yes")

else:
    print("No")
```

Console (Negative Case):

```
5
85 25 65 21 84
No
```

Console (Positive Case):

```
5
85 25 65 21 80
Yes
```